# Convert anonymous type to array or arraylist. Can it be done

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Trying to retrieve data using linq from a database. I would like to use anonymous types and convert to an Ilist, Array, ArrayList or Collection.   The data is used in a third party object that accepts Ilist, arraylist or collections.

I can't seem to get this to work. I get the following error, "Sequence operators not supported for type 'System.String'"

```
using (var db = new dbDataContext())
{
    var query = from e in db.people
                select new
                {
                    Count = e.LastName.Count()
                };

    Array test;
    test = query.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Odd, this works for me:

            int[] iss = { 324, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

            var query = from e in iss
                        select new
                        {
                            Count = e
                        };

            Array test;
            test = query.ToArray();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's got nothing to do with converting the results to array lists, or even anonymous types. Here's another version of your code which will fail:

```
using (var db = new dbDataContext())
{
    var query = db.people.Select(x => x.LastName.Count());
    foreach (int x in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

That will still fail in the same way - because it's the translation of this bit:

```
x => x.LastName.Count()
```

into SQL which is causing problems.

Change it to:

```
x => x.LastName.Length
```

and I suspect you'll find it works. Note that this isn't really a C# issue - it's just LINQ to SQL's translation abilities.

I would suggest that you *don't* use an anonymous type here though - it's pointless. Maybe this isn't your complete code, but in general if you find yourself creating an anonymous type with a single member, ask yourself if it's really doing you any good.

Comment: Why is it pointless?  What would be the best way to get SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table in LINQ?

Comment: @Dwight T: I'd use `db.people.Count()`. Even if you need filtering etc, you don't need an anonymous type.

Answer (score 2):

The ArrayList class has a constructor that accepts ICollection.
You should be able to feed it a List version of your LINQ result.

```
using (var db = new dbDataContext()) {
        var query = from e in db.people
                    select new { Count = e.LastName.Count() };

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList(query.ToList());
}
```

I don't have Visual Studio here (I'm on my Mac), but it might be of help.
(ToArray should suffice as well)

You might need to replace your Count() by Length.